# Jquery - how do i call a click event on this link

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html looks like this

```
<li>
     <div class="patient-details">
                   <span class="patent-name-heading">
                        <a id="Will simth" href="---- "?patientId=12</a>
                  </span>
      </div>
  </li>
```

Notice the id has a space in it.

I tried this

```
 $("#patientSelection li").click(function() {
            var res = $(this).find(".patent-name-heading a").attr("id");
            var url=  "#" + res  ;
            console.log(url);
            $(url).click();
         });
```

I also tried this

```
 $("#patientSelection li").click(function() {
   $(this).find(".patent-name-heading a").click()
});
```

and I get the error

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at RegExp.exec (<anonymous>)
    at RegExp.[Symbol.match] (<anonymous>)
    at String.match (native)
    at HTMLLabelElement.<anonymous> (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5:14722)
    at Function.each (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2:2975)
    at m.fn.init.each (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2:835)
    at m.fn.init.toggleClass (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5:14581)
```

However its not working. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You should never have a space in an ID.  (In fact, in HTML4+ it shouldn't even work.......)     And your anchor tag is not syntactically valid anyway.

Comment: An `id` attribute should not contain spaces. This is invalid markup.

Comment: Also click `<>` to create a snippet - your code is not valid in any way - the A tag is not closed correctly

Comment: Why not just stretch the `<a>` with CSS to width of `<li>`? There is no need of js here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't work since your `id` attribute value contains space, the resultant selecor would be `#Will simth` which search for tag `simth` within an element has `Will` as id.

Instead directly fire click event or escape the space in id [selector using `\\`](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

```
$("#patientSelection li").click(function() {
   $(this).find(".patent-name-heading a").click()
});
```

For escaping the space you can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method or use [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

```
$(url.replace(/ /g,'\\ ')).click();
// or
$('[id="' + url + '"]').click();
```

---

**UPDATE :** To prevent event bubbling upto the DOM tree use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) method or check the [`event.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property is not the `a` tag using [`is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/) method.

```
$("#patientSelection li").click(function() {
   $(this).find(".patent-name-heading a").click()
}).find(".patent-name-heading a").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation()
});
```

or

```
$("#patientSelection li").click(function(e) {
  if(!$(e.target).is('.patent-name-heading a'))
    $(this).find(".patent-name-heading a").click()
})
```

Comment: @JamesFranco : what are trying to achieve with the click event ?

Comment: I want jquery to simulate a click on that link

Comment: I tried the last one and looks like it goes into the conditional statement but nothing happens `$("#patientSelection li").click(function(e) {
     if(!$(e.target).is('.patent-name-heading a')) {
         console.log("found");
         $(this).find(".patent-name-heading a").click()
     }
    })`

Comment: @JamesFranco : what are you expecting ?

Comment: I was expecting it to go to the url in `href="---- "?patientId=12` ?

Comment: @JamesFranco : not a valid format of attribute `href="---- "?patientId=12 ?` , it should be within `""`

Comment: It actually is the code is actually python i reduced it to a simpler form. The problem is if that page didnt exist i would know. The request of the new page is not hitting the back server

Comment: this worked  `var d = $(this).find(".patent-name-heading a");
         console.log(d.attr("href"));
         d.attr("href").click();`

Comment: @JamesFranco : did you tried clicking on the `a` directly without any handlers ?

Comment: @JamesFranco : `d.attr("href").click();` - this line would throw error in console, since `attr("href")` returns a string

Comment: @JamesFranco You can do  `widow.location = d[0].href` , which direcly redirect to that page

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `span` as the click area, selecting the `class` attribute rather than the ID, and use the href property rather than the ID:

```
 $(".patent-name-heading").click(function() {
            var res = $(this).find(".patent-name-heading a").attr("href");
            var url=  "#" + res  ;
            console.log(url);
            $(url).click();
         });
```